# Execute code with random delay on Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, random, time

I want to execute my function with random delay 
I tried several solutions but nothing worked

My code look like this

```
for i in (1..10)
  puts "Love Stack"
end
```

I have tried this :

```
def every_n_seconds(n)
  loop do
      before = Time.now
      yield
      interval = n-(Time.now-before)
      sleep(interval) if interval > 0
  end
end

for i in (1..10)
  a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  a.shuffle!
  b = a[1]
    every_n_seconds(b) do
      for i in (1..10)
        puts "test"
      end
    end
end
```

Have you a solution ?

Comment: You can use `rand(10)` method to generate a random number between 0 and 9.  It is not clear whether each invocation of your code should be followed by random delay or same delay but whose value was randomly picked.

Comment: What behaviour/errors  are you getting from the code you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible way - Here `rand(10)` is used to generate a random number between `0` and `9`, and the value is used to sleep for that many seconds.  `sleep(n)` will sleep for `n` seconds.

```
def with_delay(n)
    puts "#{Time.new} Will sleep for #{n} seconds"
    sleep(n)

    puts "#{Time.new} Yielding now..."
    yield
end

5.times do
    with_delay(rand(10)) do
        puts "   Thanks for yielding"   
    end
end
```

Output:

```
2015-12-28 22:53:59 +0530 Will sleep for 1 seconds
2015-12-28 22:54:00 +0530 Yielding now...
   Thanks for yielding
2015-12-28 22:54:00 +0530 Will sleep for 0 seconds
2015-12-28 22:54:00 +0530 Yielding now...
   Thanks for yielding
2015-12-28 22:54:00 +0530 Will sleep for 7 seconds
2015-12-28 22:54:07 +0530 Yielding now...
   Thanks for yielding
2015-12-28 22:54:07 +0530 Will sleep for 5 seconds
2015-12-28 22:54:12 +0530 Yielding now...
   Thanks for yielding
2015-12-28 22:54:12 +0530 Will sleep for 2 seconds
2015-12-28 22:54:14 +0530 Yielding now...
   Thanks for yielding
```